# Why cannot refer to the embed namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, refer

I got three files in one project

one is

```
namespace sql
{
    namespace detail
    {
        void getColumnValue();
    }
}
```

the other one is

```
namespace detail{
.........
}
```

the third one is

```
#include "first_file"
namespace sql
{
template<typename TheStruct>
    class RowStruct {

        public:
            void shouldCombine()
           {
                sql::detail::getColumnValue();          
           }
}
```

those three files are both in the same projects and in the same outer namespace.
but then I build ,I got an error to say ":sql::detail' has not been declared
" for the third file.

why I just cannot refer to the "detail" in "sql", do I miss something?  If I use "detail::" in stead of "sql::detail::" in third file then it will go the the detail:: declared in second file which is not something I want.

Comment: Is the `detail` namespace actually declared inside `sql`? That isn't what you show

Comment: Are you sure you have the necessary `#include`s? Because otherwise I don't see anything wrong with this (other than a missing `};` for the `RowStruct` class).

Comment: Is the first in a header file? Do you include it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, I have included the first file in the third file

Comment: @DrewMcGowen yes, I have already included the first file in the third file, I cannot see why it does not work

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment "those three files are both in the ... same outer namespace"? Could you include the location of this "outer namespace" in your question? Because you're doing it right other than that. And having that wrong could cause what you're seeing (e.g. if in your third file you've put the #include inside the namespace declaration).

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the first file (I assume that it's a header file) into the third file.

```
#include "sql_detail.h"

namespace sql
{
template<typename TheStruct>
    class RowStruct {

        public:
            void shouldCombine()
           {
                sql::detail::getColumnValue();          
           }
    };
}
```

and, in the second file, don't you wanted to say?:

```
namespace sql{
namespace detail{
//..definitions
}}
```

Comment: the second file is not under the namespace sql, so that's why I need to specify sql::detail:: in the third file instead of detail::

Comment: and also I have already include the "sql_detail.h" in the third file, seems still not working

Comment: @user1853170 *"so that's why I need to specify sql::detail::"* -- that's incorrect. From inside `sql::`, `detail::` is `sql::detail::`. The fact that you find you need the `sql::` at all is further evidence of a problem.

Comment: it does compile, what is exactly your compiler says?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "outer namespace" you allude to is the problem. The way you should define this outer namespace is like this:

```
// file1
namespace outer {
  namespace sql {
    namespace detail { ... }
  }
}

// file3
#include "file1"

namespace outer {
  namespace sql {
    namespace detail { ... }
  }
}
```

If you put the `#include "file1"` inside the `namespace outer` in file3, you would get problems like you're seeing.

Also, note that if you're inside `namespace sql` (anywhere, including file3), you shouldn't need to explicitly say `sql::detail::`. Simply `detail::` is sufficient from inside `namespace sql` to give you `sql::detail::`. And that's irrespective of any `namespace detail` definitions in other namespaces (i.e. your file2 does not change that).

Comment: So your suggestion is to put the "#include file1" outside of "namespace outer"?? It seems that is what I did, but still got the problem :(